# gitlab-runner with docker+machine (to AWS) not working

Tags: amazon-ec2, gitlab, docker-machine

I have a question regarding gitlab-runner, docker+machine and AWS. I have setup gitlab-ce (works great, as usual), and a second server with gitlab-runner.

The gitlab-runner server is configured to use docker+machine which should connect to AWS. This is my config.toml (https://pastebin.com/BA15SSf8).

`gitlab-runner verify` says everything seems okay (runner is alive), but when I do `gitlab-runner run`, it spews a lot of errors               (https://pastebin.com/M1VQz50C), tries to start instances on AWS and fails at that, staying in a loop until I have a large amount of terminated runners on EC2 which are never used. Also, on my gitlab-server, no runners ever show up in the Runner page on the adminpanel.

I'm pretty sure I'm doing something wrong, but for the life of me I can't figure out what's the problem.

I used https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/blob/master/docs/configuration/autoscale.md to set all this up.

Comment: Have you tried using docker-machine to create an EC2 instance (from outside your runner)?

Comment: I did, yes. This worked fine, instances were properly made on EC2 in this situation

Comment: Apparently, my problems were solved by doing an upgrade over the weekend to gitlab-runner 1.6.0
I have not changed anything at all, but when I came back after the weekend, upgraded GitLab, the whole setup worked without a hitch.